# Uso di "soverchio" e "soverchiare"

Tags: word-usage

Controllando il significato di "soverchio" ho visto che il primo significato citato dai dizionari è quello di: "eccessivo, esagerato". Anche il primo significato "soverchiare" è quella di: "esagerare". Nella mia esperienza  i significati più comuni sono quelli figurati di sopraffazione e sopraffare, mentre quelli letterari sono molto meno comuni.  È corretta questa mia impressione?

***[Soverchio](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/soverchio.shtml)***:

come aggettivo:

> - agg. ***Eccessivo, esagerato***. In funzione di avv., eccessivamente.

come sostantivo:

> - 1)  ***eccesso, sovrabbondanza***.
> - 2) ***Sopraffazione, sopruso***,  avv. soverchiamente, esageratamente
>     • sec. XIII

***[Soverchiare](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/soverchiare.shtml)***:

> - 1) lett. ***Andare oltre, superare qlco.***
> - 2) fig. ***Imporsi con la forza, sopraffare qlcu.***: s. i deboli; vincere su qlco. per intensità: il rumore soverchia le voci
>     • sec. XIII

Hoepli

Comment: La domanda mi sembra interessante perché sono parole che non conosco e mi piacerebbe imparare a usarle.

Comment: Personalmente credo che la tua impressione sia giusta per quanto riguarda il verbo (meno per il sostantivo), ma indipendentemente da questo, come saprai quasi sempre i dizionari danno le varie accezioni nell'ordine cronologico in cui si sono sviluppate, indipendentemente dall'uso attuale. Saranno poi le marche d'uso “lett.” (o “letter.”), “ant.” etc. a suggerire quali usi siano più diffusi oggi.

Comment: @DaG Non sapevo che questo fosse l'ordine adottato dai dizionari. Buono a sapersi, anche se a me sembra una scelta abbastanza discutibile (la frequenza d'uso, anche approssimativa, sarebbe a mio parere un parametro più utile).

Comment: @DaG -  che riguardi più il verbo che il sostantivo è una tua impressione o hai qualche dato a conforto?

Comment: È un'impressione, @Gio: per questo ho scritto “Personalmente credo” e l'ho messo come commento e non come risposta. Mi limito a osservare che nell'uso comune non ricordo di aver letto o sentito “Ho subito un soverchio” o cose del genere. Inoltre vedo adesso che il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/soverchio/) dà questa accezione come “ant.” Hai provato a vedere gli usi in qualche campione di libri recenti con Google Books?

Comment: @DaG - la mia maggiore  perplessità riguarda soverchio come aggettivo. Sembra sia più comune di quello che pensavo. Anzi, io non l'avevo mai sentito usare con quella accezione, forse in testi letterari ma non ne sono sicuro. Ma mi rendo conto che forse la domanda non ha molto senso.